# Symfony Variable Not Being Passed to Twig Resource

Tags: php, forms, email, symfony, twig

I have inherited a PHP Symfony2 app. In the app I have a form that upon submission is suppose to send out an email, but one of the variables isn't being passed correctly to the email. (even taking all the variables out of the email template the submission will still not be be processed)

**I know this is a lot of code to look at, so maybe you might provide a good way to at least start working on this problem... I'm still very new to Symfony.**

I'm getting the following error for the email (statusChange.txt.twig)

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a NULL variable ("") in MainBundle:Email:statusChange.txt.twig at line 1
```

Here is the first controller that displays the form

```
/**
 * @Route("/manage/site/compliance/{id}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function complianceAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('site', 'compliance', 'criterion', 'category'))
        ->from('MainBundle\Entity\Site', 'site')
        ->join('site.compliance', 'compliance')
        ->join('compliance.criterion', 'criterion')
        ->join('criterion.category', 'category')
        ->where('site.id = :site_id')
        ->andWhere('site.active = true');

    $qb->setParameter('site_id', $id);
    $site = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    if (!$site) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Site not found.');
    }
    $site = array_shift($site);

    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'permissions_error',
            'You do not have permission to review the ‘'.$site->getTitle().'’ site.'
        );
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manage_index'));
    }

    $statuses = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Status')
                   ->findAll();

    $reviewStatusManager = $this->get('ReviewStatusManager');
    $nextReviewStatus = $reviewStatusManager->getNextReviewStatus($site, $user);

    $form = $this->createForm(new SiteComplianceType(), $site, array(
        'em' => $em,
    ));

    return array(
        'user' => $user,
        'site' => $site,
        'statuses' => $statuses,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'nextReviewStatus' => $nextReviewStatus,
    );
}
```

And here is the second controller that is the ProcessAction

```
/**
 * @Route("/manage/site/compliance/{id}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function complianceProcessAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('site', 'compliance', 'criterion', 'category'))
        ->from('MainBundle\Entity\Site', 'site')
        ->join('site.compliance', 'compliance')
        ->join('compliance.criterion', 'criterion')
        ->join('criterion.category', 'category')
        ->where('site.id = :site_id');
    $qb->setParameter('site_id', $id);
    $site = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    $site = array_shift($site);

    $form = $this->createForm(new SiteComplianceType(), $site, array(
        'em' => $em,
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $reviewStatus = $this->get('ReviewStatusManager')->getNextReviewStatus($site, $user);
        $noChangeReviewStatus = ($reviewStatus->getMessage() === $site->getReviewStatus()->getMessage());
        if (!$noChangeReviewStatus) {
            $site->setReviewStatus($reviewStatus);
        }
        $statusManager = $this->get('StatusManager');
        $newStatus = $statusManager->getNextStatus($site);
        $site->setStatus($newStatus);

        $mailer = $this->get('EmailDispatcher');
        if ($reviewStatus->getMessage() == 'Review complete') {
            $mailer->sendStatusChangeEmail($site);
        }
        elseif(strpos($reviewStatus->getMessage(), 'Awaiting review') === 0 && !$noChangeReviewStatus) {
            $mailer->sendAwaitingReviewEmail($site);
        }

        $action = new Action();
        $action->setSite($site);
        $action->setTask(
            $this->getDoctrine()
                 ->getRepository('MainBundle:Task')
                 ->findOneBy(array('verb' => 'review'))
        );
        $action->setPerformer($user);
        $action->setPerformed(new \DateTime("now"));
        $action->setIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $action->setComments($site->getStatus()->getName());
        $em->persist($action);
        $site->addAction($action);
        $site->setChecked(new \Datetime());

        $em->flush();
        $redirectUrl = $this->generateUrl('view_site_compliance', array('id' => $site->getId()));
        return $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
    }

    die("failed");
}
```

statusChange.txt.twig (email template)

```
We have updated the status of the following site to {{ site.status.name }}

Name: {{ site.title }}
URL: {{ site.url }}

For more information about your site's status, you can view the compliance report available at {{ url('view_site', {'id': site.id, 'tab': 'status'}) }}
```

Any help is appreciated!

***(Additional info)***
EmailDispatcher.php

```
public function sendStatusChangeEmail(MainBundle\Entity\Site $site)
{
    foreach ($site->getOwners() as $owner) {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('[A-Z Manager] Status Change: '.$site->getTitle())
            ->setSender('redacted@google.com')
            ->setFrom('redacted@google.com')
            ->setTo($owner->getEmailAddress())
            ->setBody(
                $this->templateEngine->render(
                    'MainBundle:Email:statusChange.txt.twig',
                    array('site' => $site)
                )
            )
        ;
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

StatusManager.php (getNextStatus function)

```
public function getNextStatus($site)
{
    $status = $site->getStatus();
    $reviewStatus = $site->getReviewStatus();

    // Don't change the status if we still needs to review
    if (strpos($reviewStatus->getMessage(), 'Awaiting review') !== 0) {

        // Let a special status override a "natural" status
        if ($site->getSpecialStatus()) {
            $status = $site->getSpecialStatus();
        } else {
            $compliance = $site->getCompliance();
            $fail = 0;
            foreach ($compliance as $report) {
                $fail += +($report->getValue() === 0 && $report->getCriterion()->getCategory()->getName() != 'mobile');
            }
            $statusName = ($fail > 0) ? 'Failed' : 'Compliant';
            $status = $this->em->getRepository('MainBundle:Status')
                           ->findOneBy(array('name' => $statusName));
        }
    }

    return $status;
}
```

Comment: Please show us EmailDispatcher service. Especially the `sendStatusChangeEmail()` method.

Comment: it looks like ``site.status`` (coming from database) is being null. Check ``{{ dump(site)}}`` to see complete ``site`` info

Comment: dumping (site) I get a blank page, but dumping (site.status.name) I get the string I want. That correct string though is not being passed...

Comment: @nostrzak, additional EmailDispatcher.php added to the post!

Comment: `$statusManager->getNextStatus($site);` returns null, check this function

Comment: @VadimAshikhman, I've included the getNextStatus($site) function. I'm still not seeing anything jump out at me.

Comment: @Moose what happens when an item has no status or its an empty status that may or may not have a name? If that case ever occurs this could happen.

Comment: Status field is not set by form or statuses with name 'Failed' or 'Compliant' dont exist in database.

Comment: @VadimAshikhman Woo! That worked. The developer had changed everything else to read 'Noncompliant' instead of 'Failed'. Changing this function to 'Noncompliant' seemed to pass the correct info. Thanks everyone!